# 'Immediately' used not as an adverb, but as a conjunction

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions, time

I'm sure that I've heard (not read) someone use the word immediately in a sentence in the same way that we would use "when" or "as soon as", and I would like to know if this is correct?

Here's an example:

```
I will send that email immediately I get into the office.
```

You can see that this usage is a direct replacement for something such as "as soon as", which would also work:

```
I will send that email as soon as I get into the office.
```

Is this correct usage of the word? Not many people use it like that and I didn't have any success Googling for it...

Comment: I think it looks like someone just left out a *when*

Comment: It might be technically legal, but is not common usage in the US.  You might use "immediately" as an adverb between two sentences, though:  "Frank, got out and went into the house.  Immediately, Joe drove off."

Comment: Please see a good dictionary.

Comment: Could someone educate me why/how "as soon as" is a "conjunction"?

Comment: In the sentence "I will send that email immediately." the word immediately makes more sense since you are conveying the immediate action of sending the email.   But in your sentence "as soon as" sounds better because it links better with "I get into the office"...What do you think about this angle?

Comment: Many people use it in the US; it's not highlly marked as British, like "Let's be about it". Like that phrase, though, it strikes me as typical of people who want to give the impression of efficiency, control, and busyness, and are always planning their next move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/immediately), it's an acceptable use of the word:

> immediately [conjunction] (chiefly British) As soon as: *let me know
>   immediately she arrives*

Comment: The operative words here are "chiefly British"

Comment: Thanks Sylverdrag, I should probably have mentioned in the question that it would have been a British person that said it!